# I want to run a ansible script onclick of button in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ansible

I used `os.system()` but it is only working for running python script. Can anyone suggest me how I can run an ansible script onclick of button in Tkinter?

Comment: Please show what you tried, and the error that you got.

Comment: @Taukeer Khan, You can use `subprocess` to call ansible script.

Comment: i have used the function os.system()                                                                         
        os.system('myfuc.py')

Comment: @ShubhamVaishnav ok but which function ,can you suggest me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subprocess.run()` method to execute Ansible script.

Below is a sample given, you can use it to execute your specific ansible script.

```
import os
import subprocess
import tkinter as tk


def call_ansible():
    print('Button Clicked')
    try:
        output = subprocess.run("/usr/bin/ansible hosts -i hosts -m ping", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
        print(output)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('450x350')
root.title('Ansible Run Test')


button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Button1", command=call_ansible)
button1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much Finally it is running.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ansible Runner which is a stable python API interface to running Ansible https://github.com/ansible/ansible-runner